# Difference between two snippets of code?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

Is there any difference in terms of performance in doing this:

```
for i in range(T):  
      arr = [int(arr_temp) for arr_temp in input().strip().split(' ')]
```

and this:

```
for i in range(T):
    arr = input().strip().split(' ')
    arr = list(map(int, arr))
```

if yes, which is better?

Comment: This is the perfect question to try out yourself; `import timeit; timeit.timeit(function)`.

Comment: Which bit are you interested in? Whether inlining the `input` makes a difference, or whether `list(map(...))` performs differently to a list comprehension?

Comment: the first loop is there because i need to create T number of arrays. I need to know if using map() and converting each string array into int will increase performance as opposed to using nested loops to achieve the same.

Comment: Have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214651/efficient-python-array-with-100-million-zeros

Answer (score 2):

According to IPython's `%timeit` function, `map` is a bit faster:

```
In [16]: s = ' '.join(map(str, range(1000)))

In [17]: %timeit [int(c) for c in s.split()]
10000 loops, best of 3: 171 µs per loop

In [18]: %timeit list(map(int, s.split()))
10000 loops, best of 3: 138 µs per loop
```

Tested with IPython 1.2.1 and Python 3.4.3 and with different input sizes (`range(1000)`, `range(10)`, and `range(100000)`).

Of course, the interesting question is: Is this part of the code slowing down your program (assuming that that's why you are asking, and not out of pure curiosity). Compared to, e.g., reading the `input` (from a file, I presume?), or doing calculations with the data, it might be pretty insignificant.

Comment: And both are completely overwhelmed by the I/O input() from the user

Comment: Is this true for different input sizes? (I.e., no "crossing" in the growth functions for the two alternatives).

Comment: @joelgoldstick Depends, maybe the `input` is coming from a file piped into the script. But I agree that it probably does not matter too much.

Comment: @dfri Good point, checking... yes, seems to be pretty much linear in both cases.